# CSS Transitions Not Working in IE

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm having a strange issue with my CSS. The code involves  tags formatted in rectangular shapes, and on hover those shapes change from white text with a green background to green text with a white background. I've used CSS transitions to do this sort of animation before (and it has worked in IE too) so I'm completely perplexed as to why it's not working now. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE is does nothing at all; it doesn't even change the colors.

Here's my CSS:

```
        #wrapper {
            width: 70%;
            margin-top: -1%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            min-width: 950px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #header {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
            box-shadow:         0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        }
        #header img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        a {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-right: 1.5%;
            width: 32.3%;
            padding-top: 5%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
            background-color: #259b24;
            opacity: 0.8;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
            box-shadow:         0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);              
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            letter-spacing: 6px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: normal;
            -o-transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
            -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
            -ms-transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
            transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
            font-size: 20px;
        }   
        a:hover {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            color: #259b24;
        }
        #right1, #right2 {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        a::first-line {
            letter-spacing: 6px;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
```

and here's my HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="logo.png" />
        </div>
        <a href="google.com" id="left1">General<br />Dermatology</a> 
        <a href="google.com" id="middle1">About Us<br />&nbsp;</a> 
        <a href="google.com" id="right1">Cosmetic<br />Dermatology</a> 
        <a href="google.com" id="left2">Patient<br />Resources</a> 
        <a href="google.com" id="middle2">News<br />&nbsp;</a> 
        <a href="google.com" id="right2">Live Chat<br />Contact Us</a> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The very first thing to do is validate your CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what version of IE.

Comment: @BobBrown, his CSS is perfectly valid . . .

Comment: OK... good.  That is *still* always the first thing to check when CSS doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache. I often had trouble with that. And be sure, that it don't run in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the float and display:inline-block properties you have on your anchor element. Transitions do work on IE since v9. But if you are having such problems with CSS3 things, especially in IE, when the book says they should work, I often find it is combining them with certain other properties that is the culprit. Floats are always a bit dicey in this situation, and the inline-block property is another one that's always worth looking at.

In this case if you take them both out of your a {...} CSS, the transition works fine (but of course, your layout is blown out of the water). I've put it into a fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/pyz6z9fk/ I am using IE11 for this.

So it looks to me as though you need to either achieve your layout some other way, or live with the transition not working in IE until (possibly!) some future version. How about putting this display into a CSS table to get your layout working nicely?

Comment: Hmm. That's really strange! Thanks a bunch, though.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Try adding the -ms-transform: ?

CSS Transitions do work in IE, just as long as its 9+, this site is a good resource for browser support info:

http://caniuse.com/#search=transform